# Unhandled exception issue vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, windows

I created a simple form which call data from the database and it works very well. The problem is it does not work on some computers. I already tried running it on 5 different computers and only 3 of them execute as it should be. The other 2 computers shows Unhandled Exception errors pop up which is "String was not recognized as a valid Date Time". When I clicked "Details" button on the pop up, it shows that the error is in this lines of codes:-

```
 SQLConnection.Open()
 cmd = New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM jobimport WHERE no =('" & jobid & "')",     SQLConnection)

 read = cmd.ExecuteReader

    If read.HasRows = False Then
        '  MessageBox.Show("No record found", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)


    Else
        Do While read.Read

            date1 = read("date")
            jobno = read("jobno")
            marking = read("marking")
            consignee = read("consignee")
            hblno = read("hblno")
            blno = read("blno")
            eta = read("eta")
            vessel = read("vessel")
            description = read("description")

        Loop

        DateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Parse(date1) ' <--- Error on this line
        TextBox1.Text = jobno
        TextBox2.Text = marking
        TextBox3.Text = consignee
        TextBox13.Text = hblno
        TextBox4.Text = blno
        TextBox6.Text = vessel
        TextBox7.Text = description

       End If

    SQLConnection.Close()
    SQLConnection.Dispose()
```

All the variables above are in String data type.

I tried to fix it by doing this

```
    DateTimePicker1.Text = date1
```

and this

```
    DateTimePicker1.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(date1)
```

but it still gives out the same error on those 2 computers while the other 3 computers works great without problem. Any idea?

Comment: Check the locale settings of these computers.

Comment: and what should I look into in that setting?

Comment: To see if there is a difference. The ones where it doesn't work might have a different locale setting, expecting a different date format (as also suggested by the first answer).

Comment: Your date and time settings is different from computer to anthor see the working one settings and set the same for else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change this line :

```
DateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Parse(date1)
```

To use [ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) supplying relevant CultureInfo as third parameter. For example :

```
DateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.ParseExact(date1, "d/m/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

With `ParseExact`, application will parse your date string using supplied `CultureInfo` regardless of locale setting used in computer it run.

Comment: Okay now it gives out a different error. "The DateTime represented by the string is not supported in calendar System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar. Sorry if I did not mention the data inside variable "date1" kind of look like this "3/1/2014"

Comment: It's run well in your computer right? what is your computer locale setting? You may need to change the third parameter to your local culture.

Comment: @HafizAbdullah updated my answer, changed second parameter of `ParseExact` according to sample date string you gave. Check if it works